# Powershell Command: HttpWebRequest stucks after fetching two requests

Tags: powershell

I have a list of URL in a text file and I want to test whether all of them are reachable or not. I fired the following command in windows powershell but somehow after displaying the status of first two requests, the command stucks somewhere and never returns. Am I missing something?

```
cat .\Test.txt | % { [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$_").GetResponse().StatusCode }
```

Text File

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

Output:

```
OK
OK
----> after that it stucks.
```

Answer (score 1):

use Invoke-WebRequest instead:

```
$sites = 'http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com','http://www.bing.com'

foreach ($site in $sites) {

  Invoke-WebRequest $site
  $site

}
```

Comment: same behavior as above. `cat .\Test.txt | % { iwr "$_" }`.

Comment: works for me - so you have some kind of issue outside of powershell

Answer (score 1):

From memory: You have to explicitly close the Response stream:

```
$req      = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($aRequestUrl);
$response = $null

try
{
    $response = $req.GetResponse()

    # do something with the response

}
finally
{
    # Clear the response, otherwise the next HttpWebRequest may fail... (don't know why)
    if ($response -ne $null) { $response.Close() }
}
```